Issue with Drawer Height in iOS Safari for ShadCN Component
Issue with Drawer Height in iOS Safari for ShadCN Component
I’m working on implementing a form page within a drawer using the ShadCN component. The functionality involves clicking a button to open the drawer and automatically focusing on an input field.
This works perfectly on Android devices, but on iOS devices (specifically Safari), I'm encountering an issue with the drawer height when the keyboard opens. The height seems to shrink and doesn’t behave as expected.
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { Drawer, DrawerContent, DrawerTrigger } from "@/components/ui/drawer";
import { ScrollArea } from "@/components/ui/scroll-area";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen">
      <Drawer>
        <DrawerTrigger>
          <Button variant={"destructive"}>Click</Button>
        </DrawerTrigger>
        <DrawerContent className="h-5/6">
          <ScrollArea>
            <div>
              <form>
                <input type="text" autoFocus />
              </form>
            </div>
          </ScrollArea>
        </DrawerContent>
      </Drawer>
    </div>
  );
}


Drawer opens and the input is focused.
The drawer maintains its height on all devices when the keyboard appears.

I had a similar problem and I solved by updating Vaul
by Emil Kowalski to its latest version and then adding the className="overflow-auto" in the container of my inputs (in your case it would be the div below ScrollArea).
you don't need to use ScrollArea in my opinion.
